# How can I solve RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 1?

Tags: flutter, dart

When I navigate to a new screen, suddenly I get an error like this. What could be the reason?

[image: As you see data is fetching from API. After fetching complete, there is no error]

[image: Error]

I tried several ways but I was unable to solve.What can be reason? I have been looking for the solution of this problem, but there is not enough info.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../providers/question_fetch.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../widgets/choice_buttons.dart';
import '../widgets/asked_questions.dart';

class SurveyScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  int index = 1;
  static String route = '/survey';
  SurveyScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SurveyScreen> createState() => _SurveyScreenState();
}

class _SurveyScreenState extends State<SurveyScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero).then((value) async {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return const Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              body: Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                color: Colors.red,
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              )));
        },
      );

      await Provider.of<QuestionFetch>(context, listen: false)
          .fetchAndSetQuestions()
          .then((_) => Navigator.of(context).pop());
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var surveyQuestions = Provider.of<QuestionFetch>(context).questions;
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          elevation: 0,
          leading: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.arrow_back,
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              )),
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
          title: Text(
            'Survey',
            style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
          ),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            const AskedQuestions(),
            ChoiceButtons(
                possibleAnswers:
                    surveyQuestions[widget.index].possibleAnswers,
                idQuestion: surveyQuestions[widget.index].id),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: most likely the `surveyQuestions` list is empty and you tried to access the element at index 1

Comment: Please check your `surveyQuestions` list that is it empty or not. I think this list is empty.